# beyond compare (4) how do I ignore case in file content when comparing folders

Tags: beyondcompare4

In beyond compare how do I ignore the comparison of some words that are contained in file inside the folder.

exemple:
in left side, i have a file in a folder that contains the word 'Hello'
in the right side, at same place, the file contains 'Tello'
I would like this to be an equal file.

also, how to ignore case in file content when performing a folder comparison. (not when doing file comparison) => in all files contained in the folder

Comment: Just check the `make Hello equal Tello` box in the options dialog.... Just kidding :) - was that a typo?

Comment: no, it's not a typo, I would like the comparison of Hello and Tello or Tutu and Tata to be considerred equals

Comment: Then I am confused. This is not case (in)sensitivity but something else. What formal rules guide what you consider equal and not equal in this context?

Answer (score 2):

To hide text differences in Beyond Compare 4's Text Compare, see the article [Define Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3) on Scooter Software's website.

To ignore differences in text file content in the Folder Compare, double click a pair of files to open them in the Text Compare. Follow the instructions at the above link, but change the dropdown of the Session Settings dialog from Use for this view only to **Use for all files within parent session** before you click OK. Then close the Text Compare.

In the Folder Compare, click the Rules toolbar button (referee icon). In the Comparison tab, check Compare Contents and select Rules-based comparison. This will compare the text contents of files in the Folder Compare using the settings you defined in the child Text Compare.

Answer (score 0):

I got case insensitivity when comparing *.txt files using "view"->"Ignore Unimportant Differences"